# How do I use j2html each method

Tags: java, j2html

How do I make use of j2htmls each method to add elements of a collection ?

They give an example on https://j2html.com/examples.html

```
// each() lets you iterate through a collection and returns the generated HTML
// as a DomContent object, meaning you can add siblings, which is not possible
// using the stream api in the previous example
body(
    div(attrs("#employees"),
        p("Some sibling element"),
        each(employees, employee ->
            div(attrs(".employee"),
                h2(employee.getName()),
                img().withSrc(employee.getImgPath()),
                p(employee.getTitle())
            )
        )
    )
)
```

But they don't define what *employees* or *employee* actually are.

In my case I want add series of Counter elements to a div (each with label) but I cannot see how to do it, so for now I am only using *j2html* for each individual counter and then wrapping it with hardcoded  tag.

```
sb.append("<div>\n");
for(Map.Entry<Integer, Counter> next:fsc.getCounters().entrySet())
{
    sb.append(label(next.getValue().getText()).attr("for","pb"+next.getKey().intValue()));
    sb.append(render(progress()
            .withId("pb"+next.getKey().intValue())
            .attr("value", next.getValue().getCounter().intValue())
            .attr("max", "100")));
    sb.append(rendern(br()));
}
sb.append("</div>\n");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so what I wasn't grasping in the example was *employees* is the collection variable and *employee* is arbitary, it is simply the local variable assigned to the loop and can be anything you want.

So now have it working.

```
sb.append(rendern(table(each(fsc.getCounters().entrySet(), next ->
        tr(
                td(
                        label(next.getValue().getText())
                                .attr(FOR,PB_PREFIX+next.getKey().intValue())),
                td(
                        iffElse(next.getValue().getBar().isIndeterminate(),
                                progress()
                                        .withId(PB_PREFIX+next.getKey().intValue()),
                                progress()
                                        .withId(PB_PREFIX+next.getKey().intValue())
                                        .attr(VALUE, next.getValue().getCounter().intValue())
                                        .attr(MAX, next.getValue().getBar().getMaximum())
                        )
                )
        )
    )
)));
```